# Cant boot from flash drive with windows

Tags: windows-7, boot

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on my computer. I loaded a legacy ISO with `dd` copy to an empty NTFS flash drive, added the "boot" flag and tried to load from the drive. I got this BIOS error:

> Error loading operation system

I tried do this without dd, just formatting the flash drive with GParted, setting the "boot" flag and copying files from the unpacked ISO to the drive, but this also doesn't work.

After that I download ms-sys, added a MBR to the flash drive with the command `sudo ms-sys -7 /dev/sdd`, tried to boot from the drive and got this error:

> This is not a bootable device. Please insert bootable floppy and press any key to try again

Any thoughts on what's wrong?

My motherboard is a Gigabyte M68MT-D3

Answer (score 0):

***FAT32 ISO Extract***: Though untested by me, it seems that formatting the **`USB`** key as **`FAT32`** and extracting the **`ISO`** onto the **`FAT32`** partition is good enough for **`Windows 10`** at least: [Making a Windows 10 install USB](https://superuser.com/a/1307603/11906). This is probably the same for Windows 7, but no guarantees - see potential alternative below. **`EFI`** apparently needs no special boot sectors  just a **`FAT32`** partition and the **`\efi\boot\boot[arch].efi`** loader (see above link).

This matches Microsoft's own documentation on the subject: [Install Windows from a USB Flash Drive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive). Quote: "*...select the FAT32 file system to be able to boot either BIOS-based or UEFI-based PCs*".

***The Windows USB/DVD Download Tool***:  For **`Windows 7`**, I would probably go for the [**The Windows USB/DVD Download Tool**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56485) to be sure. It will create a bootable USB or DVD for you. [**ISO Download**](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows7).

---

***Some Links***:

- [How to create ISO for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49465119/129130)

  - Deleted content, but maybe useful still?
  - More on license recovery and retrieval for example.

Comment: I try format flesh to FAT32, this dont affect. I use legacy ISO because my motherboard dont support UEFI. I cant download WIndows USB tool because I cant install windows

Comment: And you can't burn the ISO to a DVD?